# Visual Basic.net execute sub on a separate process

Tags: vb.net, process, multiprocessing

I have the following issue: I'm using a VB.net program to programmatically create some PDF file. The problem is that there must be a bug somewhere in the printing to pdf routines and the PDF file is not correctly closed at the end of the procedure. I'm fairly confident that I did everything I could to close it, so I'm thinking of a workaround. (Edit for clarity: I tried different libraries and tools for printing to PDF such as Adobe, CutePDF and others, every time the file remained open so it looks like a bug in the vb.net handling of this task..)

Is there a way to launch the printing sub on a separate process, similarly to what I could do using the `BackgroundWorker` so that when I'm done with it I can kill that process and free the file? I cannot kill the main process that creates the file since it is my main application and I need it open. I must be able to do multiple prints to the same PDF file, so I need to programmatically delete it between one print and the other, something I cannot do if it is locked by the main process.

I tried googling a bit but I couldn't find a way to easily execute a sub on a separate process and I would really like to avoid creating an ad-hoc dll and run it on a separate process, if I can.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Maybe we can help identify the error in the code. Post your code. AFAIK, there is no way to run a method in a separate process.

Comment: Are you looking to launch it in separate `Process` or separate `Thread`? you seem to have used these terms interchangeably. `BackgroundWorker` works on a separate `Thread`.

Comment: I'm not sure, if I kill the thread the file locks are released? In that case, a thread should suffice. I asked about the process because with processes I'm sure that the file locks will be released. Anyway, code coming soon..

Answer (score 1):

To run code in a separate process, you need to run it in a separate executable.

You could split your code out and create a new exe from the part that does the printing.

You could then run this from the main application like so:

```
Process.Start("C:\Path\Printing.exe")
```

However, it sounds like you want to run code in a separate thread. For this you can use a [Background Worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or create a Thread object and call a method directly:

```
Dim thr As new Thread(Sub() Printing)
thr.Start
```